# Prove or disprove that A and B are similar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the matrices: 
$A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ 
$B = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 1 \\ -2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Now, how can I check if they are similar or not? I tried to diprove that they are similar by checking if their determinants, trace and rank is equal, they are so what can I do from here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Martinargerami Thank you